# Is there a better way to iterate over multidimensional array?

Tags: multidimensional-array, d

I have a dynamic 3d array of numbers and currently I'm doing it like I usually would in C:

```
for (auto i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (auto j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        for (auto k = 0; k < size; k++) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Looks pretty ugly. Is there a shorter and maybe more "elegant" way of doing this in D?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using foreach is probably most idiomatic approach in D. It is possible to iterate by both index and value or value only.

```
import std.stdio;

void main () {

auto arr3 = [ [[1 ,2 ,3 ]], [[4 ,5 ,6 ]], [[7 , 8, 9]], 
              [[11,12,13]], [[14,15,16]], [[17,18,19]] ];

    foreach (index3, arr2; arr3)
    foreach (index2, arr1; arr2)
    foreach (index1, val ; arr1) {
        assert (val == arr3[index3][index2][index1]);
        writeln (val);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import std.array;

    foreach(el;join(join(arr3))){
        writeln (el);
    }
```

however this way you can't differentiate between which lower array you access (unless you add a separator as second argument in the join functions)